# Yii2 RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, yii2, валидация

Пишу

```
$validator = new RegularExpressionValidator();
$validator->pattern = '/[^а-яА-Я.,!()0-9 ]/u';
```

Получаю

> Exception (Invalid Configuration) 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException'
>   with message 'The "pattern" property must be set.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете валидатор. Валидатор в Yii2 создан таким образом, чтобы его можно было использовать в объектах, которые должны быть валидированы. То есть, по сути, модель сама должна себя свалидировать при помощи всех подключенных к ней валидаторов.

Когда Вы пытаетесь создать объект типа `RegularExpressionValidator`, в конструкторе вызывается `init()` метод, в котором уже должен быть задан конфиг для валидатора, то есть его `pattern`. Именно в этот момент кидается Exception. До следующей строчки просто дело не доходит.

Чтобы создать экземпляр валидатора с заданным конфигом, Вам необходимо воспользоваться конструктором с конфигом, переданным в параметры:

```
$validator = new RegularExpressionValidator(['pattern' => '/[^а-яА-Я.,!()0-9 ]/u']);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает. Странно, делал по анологии с ImageValidator

`$validator = new \yii\validators\ImageValidator();
$validator->maxSize = 1024*1024;`

С ним все без проблем работает

Comment: `maxSize` там, скорее всего, не является обязательным параметром.
Если неправильный подход где-то работает, это не значит, что он правильный;-)
Поэтому следует и там поменять код, дабы в будущем программисты голову не ломали.

Comment: Ок, еще раз спасибо за помощь.